# Return Object with different scope based on Conditional Logic (C#)

Tags: c#

I've been a developer (also in a professional capacity) for a little while now and really never focused on clean / well structured code. As completely self taught I guess I'm missing some of the fundamentals. Reading books never fills the gaps. So I hope to get some great experience from this post.

So to the point, I have a method that returns an object (Campaign) based on conditional logic.

If I can get the object via the "CampaignViewMode" then it must have been "viewed" so therefore GET
ELSE Get last inserted

- 1, Get if it has been recently viewed (Cookie)
- 2, Else just get the last Inserted.

Pretty basic but the code has a serious "code smell" (repetition). In an ideal world I'd like to remove the conditional.

```
  public Campaign GetDefaultCampaign()
    {
        Campaign campaign = null;

        using (UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository())
        {   
            var user = userRepo.GetLoggedInUser();

            if (user != null)
            {
                string campaignViewMode = "";
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CampaignViewMode"] != null)
                {
                    campaignViewMode = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CampaignViewMode"].Value.ToString();
                }

                //Get Last worked on/viewed
                campaign = _context.tbl_Campaign
                    .Where(x => x.Name == campaignViewMode & x.tbl_UserToCampaign
                                                                .Where(z => z.UserId == user.UserId & z.CampaignId == x.CampaignId)
                                                                .Select(u => u.UserId)
                                                                .FirstOrDefault() == user.UserId)
                    .Select(y => new Campaign()
                    {
                        CampaignId = y.CampaignId,
                        Name = y.Name,
                        WebName = y.WebName,
                        DateAdded = y.DateAdded
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

                //Or get last inserted
                if (campaign == null)
                {
                    campaign = _context.tbl_Campaign
                    .Where(x => x.Name == campaignViewMode & x.tbl_UserToCampaign
                                                                .Where(z => z.UserId == user.UserId & z.CampaignId == x.CampaignId)
                                                                .Select(u => u.UserId)
                                                                .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateAdded).FirstOrDefault() == user.UserId)
                    .Select(y => new Campaign()
                    {
                        CampaignId = y.CampaignId,
                        Name = y.Name,
                        WebName = y.WebName,
                        DateAdded = y.DateAdded
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }
        return campaign;
    }
```

Could you kindly point me in the right direction of removing the conditional or at the very last reduce the "smell" ?

Fully appreciate your time!

Regards,

Comment: This should probably be posted on code review...

Comment: @RonBeyer I was going to add to "CodeReview" but I assumed because there's an inconsistency in the logic it's probably better off here. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's alot going on here. Here's what I'd do.

1. Don't new up instances (as you do with Repository). Code against abstracts (IRepository) which is provided by a DI container which is injected into the class constructor.
2. Remove the duplication that maps your data model to your returned model (Select(x=> new Campaign()). Extract this out as a method or a separate responsibility entirely.
3. Remove the huge nested if(user!=null). Check for this right up front and return if it is null.
4. Refactor the two fetching operations behind an interface (IGetCampaigns) and create two classes; one that fetches the latest inserted, and one that fetches the last viewed/worked on. Inject one into the other to form a decorator chain, wired up by your DI container.

Probably a lot to take in if you're unfamiliar with these concepts; happy to go through this offline if you'd like.

Comment: I'd love to go through this further.

Comment: eagerly awaiting a more thorough explanation.